# SQLAlchemy query.filter returned no FROM clauses due to auto-correlation

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm a beginner SQLAlchemy user frustrated with the extensive documentation.

I have a newsfeed that is updated when a new **revision** is made to some **content** object. **content** always has at least one **revision**. **content** is related to 1 or more **topics** through an association table. I'm given a set of **topic.id**s T, and would like to show the N most recent "approved" revisions belonging to a row in **content** that has at least one **topic** in T. ("approved" is just an enum attribute on **revision**)

Here are the models and the relevant attributes:

```
class Revision(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'revision'

    class Statuses(object): # enum
        APPROVED = 'approved'
        PROPOSED = 'proposed'
        REJECTED = 'rejected'
        values = [APPROVED, PROPOSED, REJECTED]
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(JSONB, default=[], nullable=False)
    content_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('content.id'), nullable=False)

class Content(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'content'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    topic_edges = relationship(
        'TopicContentAssociation',
        primaryjoin='Content.id == TopicContentAssociation.content_id',
        backref='content',
        lazy='dynamic',
        cascade='all, delete-orphan'
    )

    revisions = relationship(
        'Revision',
        lazy='dynamic',
        backref='content',
        cascade='all, delete-orphan'
    )

class TopicContentAssociation(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'topic_content_association'
    topic_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('topic.id'), primary_key=True)
    content_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('content.id'), primary_key=True)

class Topic(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'topic'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
revisions = session.query(Revision).outerjoin(Content).outerjoin(Topic).filter(
    ~exists().where(
        and_(
            Topic.id.in_(T),
            Revision.status == Revision.Statuses.APPROVED
        )           )   
).order_by(Revision.ts_created.desc()).limit(N)
```

and this error is happening:

Select statement returned no FROM clauses due to auto-correlation; specify correlate(<tables>) to control correlation manually.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM topic, revision 
WHERE topic.id IN (:id_1, :id_2, :id_3...) 
AND revision.status = :status_1
```

The interesting part is that if I remove the and_ operator and the second expression within it (lines 3, 5, and 6), the error seems to go away.

BONUS: :) I would also like to show only one **revision** per row of **content**. If somebody hits save a bunch of times, I don't want the feed to be cluttered.

Again, I'm very new to SQLAlchemy (and actually, relational databases), so an answer targeted to a beginner would be much appreciated!

EDIT: adding `.correlate(Revision)` after the `.where` clause fixes things, but I'm still working to figure out exactly what is going on here.

Comment: Please post the sqlalchemy model definitions you're using, and the desired SQL you want sqlalchemy to generate.

Comment: Thanks @HaleemurAli - I've added the relevant SQLAlchemy models. Please bear with me as I'm new to both sql and sqlalchemy, which makes this problem difficult for me. This "correlate" operator (is that what it's called?) is new to me, and it's not clear what it is doing the results of my query. An explanation of why it fixed the described error and what it did would be a great start!

Comment: Something's off with your example code. There is no table named `content`, yet there's a foreign key reference to it. The model `Content` maps to table named `revisions` but does not specify any columns. The relationships specified therein seem to my cursory examination better situated in the model `TopicContentAssociation`.

Comment: You are right, @HaleemurAli - I must have messed up copy/pasting from my editor. I'll fix things up...

Comment: @HaleemurAli I've gone through this a few times and hopefully addressed your concerns by adding in a missing ```content_id``` attribute to ```Revision```, which I mistakenly didn't copy/paste. The model named ```Content``` defines an attribute named ```revisions``` without a primary join on purpose. I'm following this pattern: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html for my ```revision```/```content``` relationship.

Answer (score 11):

This is a very late response, but I am replying in case someone finds this topic.

Your second expression within the exist statement (Revision.status == Revision.Statuses.APPROVED) calls the table Revision for a second time in your query. The first time you call this table is by writing "session.query(Revision)"

If we "translate" your exists statement in PostgreSQL it would be:

```
EXISTS (SELECT 1 
        FROM Revision
        WHERE topic.id IN (:id_1, :id_2, :id_3...) 
        AND revision.status = :status_1
)
```

Calling the same table twice (FROM Revision) in the same query is not allowed unless you use an alias. So, you can create an alias of the desired table, using the aliased() function and solve your problem. Your code should be fine like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased

aliasRev = aliased(Revision)

revisions = session.query(Revision).outerjoin(Content).outerjoin(Topic).filter(
    ~exists().where(
        and_(
            Topic.id.in_(T),
            aliasRev.status == Revision.Statuses.APPROVED
        )           )   
).order_by(Revision.ts_created.desc()).limit(N)
```